# How does operator overloading work in this case?

Tags: c++

I get how this operator overloading works here in this code.....

```
class operatorOver {
public:
    int a, b, c;
};

operatorOver operator+(const operatorOver &a, const operatorOver &b) {
    operatorOver aa;
    aa.a = b.a + a.a;
    return aa;
}

int main()
{
    operatorOver aaa, bbb, ccc;

    aaa.a = 100;
    bbb.a = 200;
    ccc = aaa + bbb;

    cout << ccc.a << endl;

    system("pause");
};
```

but this version I don't understand how this one works here....

```
class operatorOver {
public:
    operatorOver operator+(const operatorOver &a) {
        operatorOver aa;
        aa.a = (*this).a + a.a;
        return aa;
    }

    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    operatorOver aaa, bbb, ccc;

    aaa.a = 100;
    bbb.a = 200;
    ccc = aaa + bbb;

    cout << ccc.a << endl;

    system("pause");
};
```

the 1st one I showed, I'm assuming the code of the operator overloading here is taking into 2 object classes in order for it to work...

but how come the 2nd example it's showing that I don't need to create another object class in it's parameters but still work... when you look in main() you see that there are 2 object classes still being passed in.... I'm lost.

Comment: By the way, I'd prefer the first way (non-member function) since in that case in `a + b` if a isn't an operatorOver and operatorOver has a conversion constructor from the type of a to operatorOver, it will be called, whereas use of a member function will not do that. Sidenote: start your classes with a capital, unless you have a good reason not to. It is the habit for most C++ developers if they use camel case. So OperatorOver rather than operatorOver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the binary operators, such as `+`, can be overloaded as member functions as well as non-member functions.

When `+` is overloaded as a member function, the function needs to be declared with one argument. When the operator is used as:

```
a + b
```

the call is resolved as

```
a.operator+(b);
```

When it is overloaded as a non-member function, the function needs to be declared with two arguments. When the operator is used as:

```
a + b
```

the call is resolved as

```
operator+(a, b);
```

Further reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh i get it now, ty! so let me get this straight... if the overload operator is defined within the class structure, it will become 'a.operator+(b)', but when the overload operator is defined outside the class structure it will become 'operator+(a, b)'....

Comment: @thundergawd, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: still got a question... why does it require a (*this) in order for the 1st example to work? is (*this) == aaa? why is this the case? EDIT - oh nvm, i just figured it out, ty very much!

Answer (score 3):

In the second example, two object are passed. There's `a` and there is also `this`. The object passed as `this` is the left side of the operation.

Also note that your member `operator+` should be const, since it doesn't mutate any data members of `this`.

Your member operator also invoke undefined behavior, since you are using a unassigned value:

```
// The member function
operatorOver operator+(const operatorOver &a) {
    operatorOver aa;

    // What is the value of aa.a? Undefined behavior!
    aa.a = aa.a + a.a;
    return aa;
}
```

To be equivalent to you non-member function, it should be this implementation:

```
// The member function
operatorOver operator+(const operatorOver &a) const {
    operatorOver aa;

    // Member `a`, could be written `this->a`
    aa.a = a + a.a;
    return aa;
}
```

Comment: yea i just updated the correction on my code lol i forgot to put (*this) in, before i had it but changed it up to demonstrate the first ex. and went back to fix up the 2nd ex. i forgot to put it correctly.....